# Onscreen keyboard Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, onscreen-keyboard

The On Screen keyboard for Ubuntu 18.10 seems to be fixed at the bottom of the screen (unmovable). In some scenarios, I need to move the on screen keyboard (float) when I don't have a physical keyboard attached. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I withdraw the question. I installed the Onboard keyboard and enabled onboard integration through Gnome Extensions. Solved the issue and has more features.